# Using Pear to send mail

Tags: php, email, unix, pear

I'm trying to use Pear to send email with smtp and ssl using the Mail class. I currently have the following in my contact form file:

```
include_once('Mail.php'); 
include_once('Mail/mime.php');
```

But I'm receiving an error:

Warning: include_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **my directory on line**

In php.ini for Core include_path currently is: .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Do I need to add the Pear directory to my php.ini file? So it would look like this:  .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/lib/php/pear

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if possible do it by editing your php.ini file directly.

Comment: I'm using set_include_path('.:/usr/local/lib/php/pear/'); in my contact file before adding to my php.ini file but I get an error: Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/Mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php/pear/') in...

Comment: Is the Mail package installed to that directory? When you look in there, what do you see?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble locating the directory for pear. Even support is unable to locate it even though it was installed on the server by default.